Whatsapp Flows error: The data exchange request failed. Please try again
I am setting up a WhatsApp flow using the WhatsApp manager to write all the Flows JSON. I've finished writing the JSON and am not seeing any errors immediately when I run the interactive preview and also set up my endpoint and tested it using Postman.
When I trigger a data exchange from the flow though I see the error:
The data exchange request failed. Please try again.
I have checked my endpoint logs and can see that it is not being triggered at all for some reason.
Is there anything I can do to figure out more specifically what the issue could be?
I tried using the interactive preview and expected it to at least trigger and call my endpoint, but I just get the error above. I'm quite sure it isn't a problem with the endpoint itself because postman worked to trigger it.

Please make sure that your endpoint is available and reachable from the internet.
If you are doing Postman request from the internal network, you might be able to reach your endpoint, but WA server from internet might be blocked.
Also make sure that you have set correct endpoint URI in the WhatsApp manager (or through API).
If the correct endpoint URI is set for the flow and endpoint is accessible from internet, you should be able to see request from WA server in your logs.
